# Select filename with highest version number

Tags: bash, shell-script, text-processing

```sh
highestVersion() {
    for TEST_PATH in `ls -a "$/TEMP"/*.flg`
    do
        echo " you are here"
        TEST_FILE=`basename "$TEST_PATH"`
        echo "$TEST_FILE"
    done
}
```

Below is the file `TEST_FILE`. In this case for example "RMG" is a book name having 4 version. How can I pick the file with latest version among these set of files and store it in a variable? How can I iterate through this, so that at the end, the variable should contain only the unique filename with highest version number?

```
ABC_EFG_FLOOL_DR3GCTEU_19951223_HANSHAKE_V03.flg
ABC_EFG_FLOOL_DR3GCTPC_19951223_HANSHAKE_V03.flg
ABC_RFTY_PICK_AMTY_19951223_HANSHAKE_V03.flg
ABC_JANE_PICK_AMTY_19951223_HANSHAKE_V02.flg
ABC_XYZ_RMG_19951223_HANSHAKE_V01.flg
ABC_XYZ_RMG_19951223_HANSHAKE_V02.flg
ABC_XYZ_RMG_19951223_HANSHAKE_V03.flg
ABC_XYZ_RMG_19951223_HANSHAKE_V11.flg
ABC_XYZ_ALG0_19951223_HANSHAKE_V02.flg
ABC_XYZ_SGFXMM_19951223_HANSHAKE_V03.flg
ABC_XYZ_STRIP_FULLREVAL_YU_1234_19951223_HANSHAKE_V02.flg
ABC_XYZ_STRIP_FULLREVAL_YU_1234_19951223_HANSHAKE_V03.flg
```

Comment: Use should ask your question in proper way. It is difficult to understand your problem. Please use appropriate keywords and title to get it correct.

Answer (score 4):

Since the version order is the same as the lexical order in your case, with a POSIX shell:

```
set -- ABC_XYZ_RMG_19951223_HANSHAKE_V*.flg
# now $1, $2... contain the files from the lowest version to highest.

shift "$(($# - 1))"
highest_version=$1

# or without shift:
eval "highest_version=\${$#}"
```

Or with `zsh` or recent versions of `bash`:

```
rmgs=(ABC_XYZ_RMG_19951223_HANSHAKE_V*.flg)
highest_version=${rmgs[-1]}
```

To do it with every file in the current directory (again with `zsh` or recent versions of `bash` (4.0 or above)):

```
highest_versions() (
  cd -P -- "$TEMP" || exit
  typeset -A a
  for f in *V??.flg; do
    a[${f%V??.flg}]=$f
  done
  printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}"
)
```

On your files, that gives:

```
ABC_XYZ_STRIP_FULLREVAL_YU_1234_19951223_HANSHAKE_V03.flg
ABC_XYZ_RMG_19951223_HANSHAKE_V11.flg
ABC_JANE_PICK_AMTY_19951223_HANSHAKE_V02.flg
ABC_XYZ_ALG0_19951223_HANSHAKE_V02.flg
ABC_XYZ_SGFXMM_19951223_HANSHAKE_V03.flg
ABC_RFTY_PICK_AMTY_19951223_HANSHAKE_V03.flg
ABC_EFG_FLOOL_DR3GCTEU_19951223_HANSHAKE_V03.flg
ABC_EFG_FLOOL_DR3GCTPC_19951223_HANSHAKE_V03.flg
```

With shells that don't support associative arrays, you can do the same by invoking a tool that does like `awk`:

```
highest_versions() (
  cd -P -- "$TEMP" || exit
  awk 'BEGIN{
    for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++) {
      key = val = ARGV[i]
      sub(/V..\.flg/, "", key)
      a[key] = val
    }
    for (i in a) print a[i]
    exit}' *V??.flg
)
```

Comment: But I am using 3.2.25(1)-release
bash version..what the modification needs to be done.can you help me?

Comment: Do it work fine with 3.2.25(1)-release bash version.Can you suggest the changes I need to make..Thank you in advance:)

Comment: Because I am getting error-- syntax error near unexpected token `)'.

Comment: @sunilkumarjn, 3.2 is from 2006, I wouldn't call that recent. See the edit for a portable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I like `perl` so I'll suggest a perlish solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my %highest_version_of;

for ( glob ( "*.flg" ) ) { 
    my ( $filename, $version ) = m/^(\w+)_V(\d+).flg/; 
    if ( $highest_version_of{$filename} //= 0 < $version ) { $highest_version_of{$filename} = $version }; 
}
foreach my $filename ( sort keys %highest_version_of ) {
    print "${filename}_$highest_version_of{$filename}.flg\n";
}
```